# How to show only selected fields in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` and cell have 5 label like 
Name : ram
DOB : 10/12/2012
Email:ram@gmail.com
Phone :1234567890
Address : Bangalore

In the `ViewController` I'm showing one popup so that user can select what field he want to see in the table view. So how to achieve this while user can also select these fields randomly than there will be space in between two fields , how to handle all these any suggestion ?

Comment: based on the selected filters just hide/unhide the labels in the cell and reload once the user selects in popup.

Comment: But if user will select filter randomly than space will come between two

Comment: "space will come between two" - you can solve this by auto layout constraints. Be aware, they it is a big area to study.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a maximum of 5 possible items to display.
Say the user taps on the button to display the popup, and choose to display 3 of the 5 items.
You could then simply create 3 labels, add them to the cells contentView, and change the height for that cell depending on the total height of the displayed labels.